# unable to include <sys/socket.h> and <arpa/inet.h>

Tags: c, sockets

I have created one C program for client and server for transferring the data from one computer to another.
The following code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char *xyz,xyz1;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port=htons(5001);
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton("192.168.0.254");
    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
    fgets(xyz);
    write(sockfd,xyz,sizeof(xyz));
    read(sockfd,xyz1,sizeof(xyz1));
    fputs(xyz);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

But it shows the following error in trubo c++ 3.0 IDE

```
  UNABLE TO OPEN INCLUDE FILE 'SYS/SOCKET.H'
  UNABLE TO OPEN INCLUDE FILE 'NETINET/IN.H'
  UNABLE TO OPEN INCLUDE FILE 'ARPA/INET.H'
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard that specifies a `sys/socket.h` file that Turbo C++ 3.0 supports. For example, [SuS v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html) and [IEEE 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html) require such a header, but TC++ 3.0 doesn't support either of them. Either use a compiler that supports the standards you plan to program to or only program to the standards your compiler supports.

Oh, and your code has lots of bugs:

```
       char *xyz,xyz1;
       sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
       saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
       saddr.sin_port=htons(5001);
       saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_aton("192.168.0.254");
       connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr));
       fgets(xyz);
```

You didn't set `xyz` to any particular value. You can't use its value yet by passing it to `fgets`. You're passing `fgets` whatever random garbage happened to be in an uninitialized pointer.

```
       write(sockfd,xyz,sizeof(xyz));
```

Since `xyz` is a pointer, `sizeof(xyz)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)`. You want to write a number of bytes equal to the size of a pointer on your platform? You need to tell `write` how many bytes you want it to write, not how big the pointer is. And, again, `xyz` doesn't point to anything yet, so you can't use its value. You're passing `write` whatever garbage value an uninitialized variable had.

```
       read(sockfd,xyz1,sizeof(xyz1));
```

Again, you use `sizeof(xyz1)`, which is the same as `sizeof(char *)` and not what you want. You also use `xyz1`'s value, by passing it to `read`, before setting it to anything. It doesn't point to anything, so you can't use it to tell `read` where to put its results.

```
       fputs(xyz);
```

The `fputs` function is *only* for C-style strings. The data you read from a socket is just raw data, it's not a C-style string. So you can't pass it to `fputs`. You throw away the return value of `read`, so you have no idea how many bytes you read -- how are you expecting `fputs` to know how many bytes to write?

Clearly, you're just starting to learn C. You must be a masochist to use a compiler that's 22 years old. For the sake of all that is holy, I hope you're not trying to learn C++ on it, because you will learn everything totally wrong for modern C++ and set yourself back significantly. Those of us who have been programming C++ for that long had to go to a lot of pain to unlearn the old stuff -- don't put yourself through that if you don't have to.